# Как правильно работать c foreach php?

Tags: php

Есть такой код:

```
foreach($pp as $pp2){
    $_SESSION['pp2'] = $pp2['id_user'];
    $_SESSION['pp3'] = $pp2['id_f'];
    $pp2a = $_SESSION['ppfriend2'];
    $pp2b = $_SESSION['pp3'];
if($people==$pp2b && $people!=$sid){
        echo 'Ок';
    } else {
        echo $people = '<input type="submit" value="Добавить">';
    }
    }
```

Проблема в том, что вот этот кусок: `echo $people = '<input type="submit" value="Добавить">';` в результате ставится несколько раз. Как правильно расположить, чтобы не было повтора?

Comment: Создайте временную переменную и заполните её,например,`true` и создайте условие на проверку ,существует ли данная переменная.Когда цикл будет снова проходиться по внутренностям(во второй раз,как пример),то он не будет выбрасывать несколько раз тот инпут.Можно

Answer (score 1):

Есть два варианта, в зависимости от того, что вам конкретно надо, если вам надо 
вывести input и затем не нужно дальше обходить цикл, используйте break

```
foreach($pp as $pp2){
            $_SESSION['pp2'] = $pp2['id_user'];
            $_SESSION['pp3'] = $pp2['id_f'];
            $pp2a = $_SESSION['ppfriend2'];
            $pp2b = $_SESSION['pp3'];
            if($people == $pp2b && $people!= $sid){
                echo 'Ок';
            } else {
                echo $people = '<input type="submit" value="Добавить">';
                break;
            }
        }
```

или как вам написали выше в комментариях, можно сделать так

```
$printInput = true;
foreach($pp as $pp2){
            $_SESSION['pp2'] = $pp2['id_user'];
            $_SESSION['pp3'] = $pp2['id_f'];
            $pp2a = $_SESSION['ppfriend2'];
            $pp2b = $_SESSION['pp3'];
            if($people == $pp2b && $people!= $sid){
                echo 'Ок';
            } else {
                if ($printInput === true) {
                echo $people = '<input type="submit" value="Добавить">';
                $printInput = false;
                }
            }
        }
```